# Child Robot not following parent in RViz

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, transform, odometry

I'm in a 2D environment in C++/ROS and I have two Robots with only Translational/Rotational velocity. They move only on the X axis and rotate on the X axis. The configuration follows this scheme:

- Robot 1: X = 618.12 | Y = 1028.39 | Angle = 0
- Robot 2: X = -0.7 | Y = 0 | Angle = 3.141592

Meaning that Robot 2 is positioned slightly off the first one and rotated by 180°, still maintaining the same height.

Everything on Rviz works, except the movement of Robot 2, which does not follow the movement of Robot 1.

My simply timeTick() function states:

```
float dt = 0.07
Pose motion(tv * dt, 0, rv * dt);
Pose next_pose(pose_in_parent * motion);
 
IntPoint ip = world->world2grid(next_pose.translation);  
int int_radius = radius * world->inv_res;

if (!world->collides(ip, int_radius)) { // We have not collided, so let's update the position
    pose_in_parent = next_pose;      
}
```

The variable `pose_in_parent` describes exactly the pose in the parent. Meaning that for Robot 2, it returns exactly the coordinates I expressed at the beginning.

Then, I update the Odometry of each Robot by:

```
geometry_msgs::Quaternion geometry_quaternion;
tf2::Quaternion tf_quaternion;

tf_quaternion.setRPY(0.0, 0.0, pose_in_parent.theta);
tf_quaternion.normalize();

// Set the components of the geometry_msgs::Quaternion
geometry_quaternion.x = tf_quaternion.x();
geometry_quaternion.y = tf_quaternion.y();
geometry_quaternion.z = tf_quaternion.z();
geometry_quaternion.w = tf_quaternion.w();

// Populate the odometry data here (position and orientation)
odom.pose.pose.position.x = pose_in_parent.translation.x;
odom.pose.pose.position.y = pose_in_parent.translation.y;    

odom.pose.pose.orientation = geometry_quaternion; // Assuming theta represents orientation

// Publish the Odometry message
robotOdometryPublisher.publish(odom);
tf2Robot();
```

And the same thing happens with the Transform tf (TransformStamped), where I simply publish a transform always based on pose_in_parent (hence the method `tf2Robot()`).

The problem now is that, if I update the Robot 2 pose_in_parent along with Robot 1 motion, it follows its parent rotation but also adds a motion to itself, so it’s spinning while rotating around its parent. In this case, RViz correctly shows the double rotation, but it’s not what I want.

If I don’t update the Robot 2 pose_in_parent along with Robot 1 motion, it simply follows the rotation of the parent and doesn’t add any additional motion (ideal case), but in RViz the arrow of the children stays still, while the one of the parent keeps spinning. This is due to the fact that pose_in_parent of Robot 2 doesn’t get updated.
If I tick/untick the Odometry of Robot 2, the arrow appears exactly where it should be (behind the Robot 1 rotated by 180°), but still stays fixed, always because pose_in_parent doesn’t get updated.

What’s the problem in this approach?

N.B. I create parent Robots by converting the global coordinates (X/Y) into World coordinates (multiplying by 0.05) and instantiate them in the World, while I create childrens based on their Pose (in case of Robot 2, I instantiate it in the World at -0.7, 0).

[image: RViz]